# mean for 2 lags, all levels

Tags: r, zoo

I have dataframe below with 3 columns. A factor, an observation and column where I want to calculate two previous observation for each level on factor.

Mean_x on row 7 would take value 5, since two last observation on "a" are 7 and 3, row 4 and 3.

I have looked a bit on zoo package. But it seems to only take the lag for all rows, now I want mean of lag 2 within each level of factor..

```
factorobservation   mean_x
1   d   8   NA
2   b   11  NA
3   a   3   NA
4   a   7   NA
5   c   1   NA
6   b   7   NA
7   a   2   NA
8   a   4   NA
9   d   9   NA
10  c   8   NA
11  d   7   NA
12  c   5   NA
13  c   6   NA
14  d   9   NA
15  a   5   NA
16  a   3   NA
17  d   7   NA
18  a   3   NA
19  d   4   NA
20  c   4   NA
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If would be helpful for us if you could illustrate the desired behavior.

Comment: Maybe try `ave`, which will operate within a group of rows (e.g., grouped by your factor).

Comment: Can you show the expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to make a function that operates within each level of your factor like so:

```
f <- function(x) {
  if (length(x) < 3) {
    rep(NA, length(x))
  } else {
    c(NA, NA, sapply(3:length(x), function(i) mean(x[i-1:2])))
  }
}
```

Then, as others have suggested, you can use `ave` to broadcast the results back to the original `data.frame`:

`df$mean_x <- ave(df$observation, df$factor, FUN=f)`

```
> df
   factor observation mean_x
1       d           8     NA
2       b          11     NA
3       a           3     NA
4       a           7     NA
5       c           1     NA
6       b           7     NA
7       a           2    5.0
8       a           4    4.5
9       d           9     NA
10      c           8     NA
11      d           7    8.5
12      c           5    4.5
13      c           6    6.5
14      d           9    8.0
15      a           5    3.0
16      a           3    4.5
17      d           7    8.0
18      a           3    4.0
19      d           4    8.0
20      c           4    5.5
```

Comment: Worked just perfect, exactly what I wanted. Million thanks :)